# How to display the tabBar on the screen after the transition

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm a beginner developing iOS apps using swift in Xcode.

***[embarrassment]***

I would like to know how to display tabBar on the screen after the transition by button.
If you press the button in FistViewController in the image below, you will go to nextViewController on the right side. I would like to know how to display the tabBar in nextViewController as well. (If you press the button to transition through the screen, the nextViewController will not display the tabBar.)

[image]

Comment: The NextViewController is a simple UIViewController, and not a UITabBarController. Create one more view controller of type UITabBarController, say NextTabBarViewController and add NextViewController within this newly created UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

When you present a view controller modally, its presentation style will be "Full Screen" by default.What you need to do is change your modalPresentationStyle

```
 guard let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVCName") else {
                return
            }
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            VC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this knowledge with me.